# C# Programming Best Practices For Mathematical Calculations

Tags: c#

Can anyone let me know where can I read the best practices to write an application that relies heavily on mathematical calculations? For example, suppose I was asked to write a C# application that generates 100 even numbers. I would write the following:

```
public void GenerateEven() {
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(i * 2);
    }
}
```

However that is not the best practice to do. The best way to generate even number would be, for example:

```
public void GenerateEven() {
    int i=0;
    while (i <200) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
        Console.Writeline(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the best mathematical practice in c# is not to use c# for mathematical calculations

Comment: Who says the second is better than the first.  The first will at least give the expected result and not run in an infinite loop

Comment: If it is something academic I suggest you take a look at [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/). You can develop your mathematical model in it and then compile it to a DLL that your C# app can use.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for http://projecteuler.net/

Comment: This belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ as it is clearly a  conceptual question about software development.

Answer (score 3):

If you're after expressiveness, take a page from functional programming:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> EvenNumbers(int start = 0)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return start;
        start += 2;
    }
}
```

Then to get your sequence:

```
var firstHundredEvenNumbers = EvenNumers().Take(100);
```

It really depends upon your goal. If you're looking for composition, the above is great. If you're looking for raw speed, then you should mash all the logic into one ball and tune the heck out of it -- but it'll be harder to work with.

Comment: How does this work? Does `EvenNumbers()` not need to return before `Take(100)` is executed? I've never used this C# pattern/idiom and it does look cool, so I'm curious.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis, `EvenNumber` is a generator function. Notice the `yield` before the `return`. It means that the loop inside never completes, however it a thread that calls into it will return when the `yield` occurs. The C# compiler achieves this by creating a new class as a state machine to track the local variable `start` in an instance of an `IEnumerator`. So if you called `EvenNumbers.Count()` the method would never return. However something like `EvenNumbers.First()` returns immediately, and the object used to track the progress is garbage collected.

Comment: This is amazing! !!

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think the second method is the best way to do it?  If I were asked to do that problem, then I would do this, so I only loop 100 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i += 2)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

As for your more general question, there is no one document or book that gives you best practices on how you should form loops or approach mathematical problems.  This is where a [computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) education comes in handy to analyze your problem and try to find an optimal solution.

In your sample problem each one of the solutions proposed (including the ones proposed by me) come down to a [big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of N, so the computational differences between these solutions are negligible.  The growth is linear with respect to N.  The only advantage my solution provides is that it only loops over the necessary items to generate the output, instead of skipping items that do not meet the criteria.

Comment: I believe zero is an [even number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero).

Comment: @BrentM.Spell I stand corrected.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may be looking for [The Art of Computer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) by Donald Knuth

Its called `the bible of all fundamental algorithms` and contains many kinds of programming algorithms and their analysis. But it does not cover any language specific moments.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to generate numbers, you can use Enumerable.Range thus:

**Edit: (rotem)**

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(1,100/ 2+ 1).Select((X) => X * 2).ToList();
```

Comment: -1 The question is not about generating even numbers

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly the question only has an example on generating numbers. Otherwise I'd make great remarks about calling external processes just like you.

Comment: And even if, `Enumerable.Range(1,100).Select(x => x*2).ToList()` is more efficient and shorter.

Comment: The question states: `where can I read the best practices to write an application that relies heavily on mathematical calculations?` The part about numbers is only the example of data.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly not a good question, not a great answer. Case closed.